# I need to change index title name with respect to a specific condition in angular how i can do this?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rope</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta property="og:title" content="tals" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Base solution for your next web application" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lykmapipo/themify-icons@0.1.2/css/themify-icons.css">
    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    
</head>

<body class="mat-typography">
    <app-root>
        <!-- <div class="root-initial-loader">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-3x fa-spin-2x"></i>
        </div> -->
    </app-root>
</body>

</html>
`your text`
```

This is my index.html file. I want to change the title name "Rope" when the client is changed. How can I do this in angular?
We cant change the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every part of you application (components or services) you can inject `Title` service, which will have a method `setTitle`.

For example, in you **app.component** you could do this:

```
  constructor(
    private titleService: Title
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const randomNum = Math.random();
    if (randomNum > .5) {
      this.titleService.setTitle("High number");
    } else {
      this.titleService.setTitle("Low number");
    }
  }
```